# How do you get a prediction for a specific value in linear regression in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

i have trained my ML model with linear regression using these

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

how do i get a prediction for a single row in the data set?

Comment: `regressor.predict(X_train)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do something like this-

```py
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

So if you want to do inference on only a single row in the dataset let's say the row at 2nd index. You would do-

```py
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn models all have a `predict` [method you can use](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

Just pass it your row as an array and you'll be fine:

`regressor.predict(x_val)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the first row, you could do

```
first_row = X_test[0] //assuming X_test is where your test data is at
y_pred = regressor.predict(first_row)
```